# Trying to display a fixed-height DIV. Why does a subsequent DIV display over the fixed-height DIV?

Tags: css, html, height

This is weird; I'm specifying the `height` of a DIV but the browser seems to display other DIVs over top of it.  An example is at http://jsfiddle.net/x48v4/ .

I tried explicity specifying `display: block;` but no dice.  Also tried specifying `min-height` but that didn't work either.  I read a promising trick involving `clear: both;` but that was also to no avail.

In the JSFiddle example, I just want the red DIV to display directly underneath the blue DIV.  Appreciate any help you can provide!

```
<html>
<body style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.5;">

<div style="width: 300px; text-align: center; margin: 0px auto;">

    <div style="height: 300px; background: #9999ff;">
        <br>
        This DIV has a blue background and is 300px tall.&nbsp; I want the red DIV below to display underneath this blue header.<br>
        &nbsp;
    <div>

    <div style="background: #ff5555;">
        But instead, this DIV is "superimposed" over the blue DIV's background-&nbsp; why is that?<br>
        I want this to be underneath the blue DIV instead.
    <div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML in your example is incomplete AND should be posted here in your question. Also, if you want the red div to appear after the blue div, put it after the blue div in your HTML, not as a child.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I've now added the HTML to the question itself too.  As far as I can tell, the red div is not a child of the blue div, but I am open to any clarifying info about that... thanks!

Comment: The div for both boxes are not correctly closed. <div> </div>. Lines 9 and 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this also as an answer. The div's are not correctly closed - for both boxes.

Here's the updated code:

```
<html>
<body style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.5;">

<div style="width: 300px; text-align: center; margin: 0px auto;">

    <div style="height: 300px; background: #9999ff;">
        <br>
        This DIV has a blue background and is 300px tall.&nbsp; I want the red DIV below to display underneath this blue header.<br>
        &nbsp;
    </div>  <!-- closed the div here -->

    <div style="background: #ff5555;">
        But instead, this DIV is "superimposed" over the blue DIV's background-&nbsp; why is that?&nbsp; I want this to be underneath the blue DIV instead.
    </div>  <!-- closed the div here -->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks!  Sorry to see that my first question on here was due to a simple typo...  but perhaps that is de rigueur.